# Prevent locked screen to be activated by mouse - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, lock-screen

I use my laptop to listen to online radio. During this, I don't need / want an active screen, so I lock the screen with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

The screen goes blank, but later gets reactivated regularly. As I listen to the radio, the screen keeps lighting up, then, like in a minute, going blank again.

I guess this might be from inputs received from a sensitive wireless mouse...

Could I configure Windows 10 to activate a locked screen only on inputs from the keyboard, but not from the mouse? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Turn the mouse OFF while using the computer this way. That works great

Comment: @John, that admittedly would work, but the physical switch on my mouse is cumbersome and thus effortful to operate even once, let alone twice each time I use the screen lock. It would be a massive degradation in UX compared to the natural ease of keyboard shortcuts. (Oops, have we found an idea? Can I set up a keyboard shortcut to disable/enable the mouse? (Probably not.))

Comment: Windows does not really separate mouse and keyboard as both are needed, so I am not aware of any way to achieve what you want

Comment: Windows 11 is the same if you upgrade and is somewhat immune to 3rd party products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not have an option to disable the mouse while the screen is
locked. You need third-party products to do that.

The following are a couple of free products that might help :

- [WinLockr](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winlockr/)
  is free and open-source. The last version is from 2018 and the developer
  seems to have abandoned the product, but it still works.
  See its description in the article
  [Improve Windows' lock screen with WinLockr](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/08/24/improve-windows-lock-screen-winlockr/).
- [Lock My PC](https://fspro.net/lock-pc/)
  is another free product. There is a paid version that seems not to
  be needed in your case.

Comment: I accept and upvote this answer for the valued information: "Windows does not have an option to disable the mouse while the screen is locked." However, I feel it important to clarify that I have not installed, and do not endorse any of the mentioned third party software.